# Can 'true' be equal to 'faithful'?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say 'true to' to mean 'faithful/loyal to', as in 'I am still true to paper books', or would it be a mistake?

Comment: It can be used in that sense.  As with any word, the meaning can be lost if used in the wrong context.

Comment: You should look it up before you ask it. See the third sense [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/true).

Comment: It's now rather old-fashioned and literary, but perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "true" is poetic and probably shouldn't be used in other contexts without sounding snooty. There are a pair of excellent examples in the song "Wharf Rat" by the Grateful Dead:
"You know I've been, I'm sure I've been, true to you.
...I know she's been, I'm sure she's been, true to me."

Comment: so if I say, "Stay true to your heart." I'm being snooty?

Comment: No; I like that example. But I still think it is a poetic sentence designed to inspire.

Comment: In valedictory salutations in letters we use truly and faithfully indiscriminately.